# Overloaded operator function returns garbage when it's not a Friend

Tags: c++

My overloaded insertion operator works fine when it's declared as a friend of my Coord class. However, when it's not a Friend, cout << myCoord seems to return GARBAGE. I don't understand why, considering how I'm not using any private member data.

```
//in my coord.cpp
ostream& operator <<(ostream& outputStream, const Coord &coord_in) {

    outputStream << "( " << coord_in.getRoom() << ", " << 
    coord_in.getRow() << ", " << coord_in.getCol() << " )";   

    return outputStream;
}

//coord.h
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#ifndef COORD_H
#define COORD_H

class Coord {
private:
int room;
int row;
int col;
public:
Coord();
Coord(int room_in, int row_in, int col_in);
/* accessor functions */
int getRoom() const;
int getRow() const;
int getCol() const;

/* mutator functions */
void setRoom(Coord coord_in, int newRoom);
void setRow(Coord coord_in, int newRow);
void setCol(Coord coord_in, int newCol);

friend ostream& operator <<(ostream& outputStream, const Coord &coord_in);
};

#endif
```

Comment: Can you show the whole class?

Comment: What does "when it's not a friend" mean? Declared as a member? Not declared at all? Declared in some other way? You need to clarify that. How do you call your operator? Where do you call it from?

Comment: Post a MCVE. Perhaps you are forgetting to declare the `operator<<` in the non-friend case; or you have an implicit conversion operator that you didn't show, or you just took out the word `friend`, etc.

Comment: I wasn't declaring the operator<<. Thank you!

Comment: @Shane: If you simply weren't declaring it, your code would not have compiled at all. Yet you claim that it output "garbage" (implying that it compiled). How is that possible?

Comment: @AndreyT: I don't know. I just know that I only had a definition when I wasn't friending my class and it compiled with garbage output. As soon as I unfriended and declared it in my header file (outside the class) it worked like I was expecting it to originally.

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with me overloading a function instead of defining an entirely new one. I don't get it either though, I'm a newb.

Comment: @Shane did the compiler give you "garbage output" (that is errors because of your bug) or did your program compile and run but generate weird output? You need to learn to accurately describe things.